# Using semaphores while modyifing file in perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, file, semaphore

I'm kind of newbie to threads in perl.

I have a file with a list of projects (each project is in a separate line), and i want to build those projects in parallel. 
Currently, each thread:

1. opens the file as "read" mode
2. saves a list of some projects (= some file lines)
3. closes the file
4. opens the file again- as "write" mode
5. rewrites it without the lines that were selected

in order to make sure each thread is the only one to access the file, im trying to use semaphore.

for some reason, threads collisons are occurred, and i can't figure out what am i doing wrong.

i can see (in my "REPORT" which also gets the current time for each build) 
that deifferent threads select the same projects from the "shared" file (it happens only once in a while, but still..)

i'm not even sure if my $semaphore decleration is legal as "my" variable.

Any help would be truly appreciated!!

Thanks.

---

here's a part of my code:

```
    my $semaphore = Thread::semaphore->new() ;

sub build_from_targets_list{

    #...
    open(REPORT, "+>$REPORT_tmp");  # Open for output
    #....
    @threads =();


    for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_cores; $i++){
        my $thr = threads->new(\&compile_process, $i,*REPORT);
        push @threads, $thr;
    }

    $_->join for @threads;
    close (REPORT);
}
### Some stuff..


sub compile_process{

    *REPORT = shift(@_);
    #...

    while (1){
        $semaphore->down();
        open (DATA_FILE, $shared_file);
        flock(DATA_FILE, 2);
        while ($record = <DATA_FILE>) {
            chomp($record);
            push(@temp_target_list,$record);    
        }


        # ... choose some lines (=projects)...
        # remove the projects that should be built by this thread:
        for ($k = 0; $k < $num_of_targets_in_project; $k++){            
            shift(@temp_target_list);

        }

        close(DATA_FILE);       
        open (REWRITE,">$shared_file");

        flock(REWRITE, 2);

        seek(REWRITE, 0, 0); 
        foreach $temp_target (@temp_target_list){

            print REWRITE "$temp_target\n";

        }

        close (REWRITE);

        ## ... BUILD selected projects...

        $semaphore->up();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, some basic cleanup of how you're dealing with files.  No point in trying to debug a thread problem if it's a simple file issue.

One must check that any file commands (open, close, flock, seek, etc...) succeed.  Either stick some `or die`s on there or `use autodie`.

Second is the use of a hard coded constant for flock.  Those are system dependent, and its hard to remember which mode 2 is.  [Fcntl](https://metacpan.org/module/Fcntl) provides the constants.

You're opening the data file for reading with an exclusive lock (2 is usually exclusive lock).  That should probably be a shared lock.  This would be unlikely to cause a problem, but it will cause your threads to block unnecessarily.

Finally, use lexical filehandles instead of a globally scoped glob.  This reduces the chance

```
use Fcntl qw(:flock);
use autodie;

open (my $data_fh, $shared_file);
flock($data_fh, LOCK_SH);
```

As a side note, the `seek $fh, 0, 0` after opening a file for writing is unnecessary.  Same goes for seek constants as for flock, use Fcntl to get the constants.

An additional bug is that you're passing in `$i, *REPORT` but `compile_process` thinks `*REPORT` is the first argument.  And again the use of global filehandles means that passing it in is redundant, use lexical filehandles.

Now that's out of the way, your basic algorithm seems flawed.  `compile_process` has each thread reading in the whole data file into the thread local array `@temp_target_list`, shifting some off of that local array and writing the rest out.  Because `@temp_target_list` is per thread, there's no coordination.  Unless `$num_of_targets_in_project` is shared and doing some sort of off screen coordination, but that's not shown.

File based locking is always going to be a little slice of hell.  Threads have much better mechanisms for coordination.  There's a much easier way to do this.

Assuming the file isn't too large, read each line into a shared array.  Then have each thread take items to work on from that array.  The array is shared, so as each element is removed the array will update for all the threads.  Something like...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $Max_Threads = 5;
my @Todo : shared;

open my $fh, "<", $work_file;
@Todo = <$fh>;
close $fh;

my @threads;
for (1..$Max_Threads) {
    push @threads, threads->new(\&compile_process);
}

$_->join for @threads;

sub compile_process {
    while( my $work = shift @Todo ) {
        ...do whatever with $work...
    }
}
```

If the file is too large to be held in memory, you can use [Thread::Queue](https://metacpan.org/module/Thread%3a%3aQueue) to build a queue of work items and add to it dynamically.